# Powershell command to list subsites and users

Tags: powershell

Looking for a PowerShell command to list SharePoint subsites with users / security groups of each that have access to each.

Comment: Please tag the SharePoint version

Answer (score 2):

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$oSite = Get-SPSite "https://webapp/sites/sitecoll"

foreach($oWeb in $oSite.AllWebs)
{
    foreach($grp in $oWeb.Groups)
    {        
        Write-Host $grp.Name
        Write-Host "-------"

        foreach($usr in $grp.users)
        {
            Write-Host $usr.DisplayName
        }
    }
}
```